# Is there a way to use next-js together with the single-spa micro frontend framework?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-react

In my work team we have a micro frontend architecture due to the large number of teams that work on the same application. Initially we are using react-js for all micro applications, but since the same react documentation suggests using a framework (next, expo, remix) we are exploring how to integrate next-js with single-spa without break what we already built but so far we have not found information about it.

We hope to find a way to use next-js together with single-spa

Comment: You should ask in the single-spa Slack channel directly, I think.  Having said that, it would be good if you explained any attempts made and any **specific** errors or problems encountered.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.